# Git pretty graph command fatal error

Tags: git

I tried this command in bash and it says fatal error, I got this syntax right from Git docs.  I'm working in Windows 8.

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --graph
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the space between the `format: "%h %s"` when you execute the command on the terminal.

Comment: duh thanks did not see it.  It looked like there was a space there from the git docs..